# Looping inside the json in stored proc DocumentDB

Tags: javascript, azure, azure-cosmosdb

I have big json that I pass to stored procedure in Cosmos DB. I need to split the json document and create multiple documents. How do I loop to the json inside the stored procedure.

Example: Using Json below I need to create a separate document for each children and another one without Children nodes. A total of 3 documents. How can I loop and split it inside the stored procedure?

```
{
  "id": "d93af7d3706e4f28882920366c017cd7",
  "FamilyId": 989,
  "LastName": "Andersen",
  "Parents": [
    {
      "FamilyName": null,
      "FirstName": "Thomas"
    },
    {
      "FamilyName": null,
      "FirstName": "Mary Kay"
    }
  ],
  "Children": [
    {
      "ChildId":001,
      "FamilyName": null,
      "FirstName": "Henriette Thaulow",
      "Gender": "female",
      "Grade": 5,
      "Pets": [
        {
          "GivenName": "Fluffy"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "ChildId":002
      "FamilyName": null,
      "FirstName": "Maria Thaulow",
      "Gender": "female",
      "Grade": 12,
      "Pets": [
        {
          "GivenName": "Grizzly"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "Address": {
    "State": "WA",
    "County": "King",
    "City": "Seattle"
  },
  "IsRegistered": false
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this sample: https://github.com/Azure/azure-documentdb-js-server/blob/master/samples/stored-procedures/BulkImport.js. Note that *currently* stored procedure can run within context of one partition key (which is provided in request options to execute the sproc), i.e. if there are multiple PK values in your docs, the docs need to be grouped by PK value.

Answer (score 0):

Actually , you can implement bulk import data via Stored Procedure.

Please refer to the code from [official tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/programming#bounded-execution).

```
function bulkImport(docs) {
    var collection = getContext().getCollection();
    var collectionLink = collection.getSelfLink();

    // The count of imported docs, also used as current doc index.
    var count = 0;

    // Validate input.
    if (!docs) throw new Error("The array is undefined or null.");

    var docsLength = docs.length;
    if (docsLength == 0) {
        getContext().getResponse().setBody(0);
    }

    // Call the create API to create a document.
    tryCreate(docs[count], callback);

    // Note that there are 2 exit conditions:
    // 1) The createDocument request was not accepted. 
    //    In this case the callback will not be called, we just call setBody and we are done.
    // 2) The callback was called docs.length times.
    //    In this case all documents were created and we don’t need to call tryCreate anymore. Just call setBody and we are done.
    function tryCreate(doc, callback) {
        var isAccepted = collection.createDocument(collectionLink, doc, callback);

        // If the request was accepted, callback will be called.
        // Otherwise report current count back to the client, 
        // which will call the script again with remaining set of docs.
        if (!isAccepted) getContext().getResponse().setBody(count);
    }

    // This is called when collection.createDocument is done in order to process the result.
    function callback(err, doc, options) {
        if (err) throw err;

        // One more document has been inserted, increment the count.
        count++;

        if (count >= docsLength) {
            // If we created all documents, we are done. Just set the response.
            getContext().getResponse().setBody(count);
        } else {
            // Create next document.
            tryCreate(docs[count], callback);
        }
    }
}
```

When stored procedure is executed from client, RequestOptions specify the partition key, stored procedure will run in context of this partition and cannot operate (e.g. create) on docs that have different partition key value.

What you can do is to execute the stored procedure from client for each partition key. For instance, if stored procedure is to bulk-create documents, you can group the docs by partition key and send each group (can be done in parallel) to the stored procedure providing partition key value in RequestOptions.

Hope it helps you.

Comment: Thanks @Jay, I've looked at the sample and it is more of bulk import. I've updated my question to be more specific.

Comment: @b_koders Hi,  I'm not sure why you need to split a complete JSON into several documents. And why the same children key appears in your JSON?
 I think Children is an array.

Comment: @b_koders Hi, any progress now?